# Continuity of multivalued function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Every multivalued function $A \rightrightarrows B$ can be thought as a function $A → \mathcal{P}(B)$, where $\mathcal{P}$ represents power set.

Let me have an "analytic" definition of continuity of such functions. A function $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ is continuous iff, for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that:
$$
\forall y \in (x - \delta, x + \delta) \quad f(y) \subset \bigcup_{u \in f(x)} (u - \epsilon, u + \epsilon)
$$

This is basically an extension of the epsilon-delta definition. An example of a continuous multivalued function is what I call "continuous signum function":

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} \{-1\} & \text{if } x < 0 \\ \{-1,0,1\} & \text{if } x = 0 \\ \{1\} & \text{if } x > 0 \end{cases}
$$

Another example is what I call "interpolated reciprocal function":

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} \{x^{-1}\} & \text{if } x ≠ 0 \\ \mathbb{R} & \text{if } x = 0 \end{cases}
$$

Here's the question. Is there a topology on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ so the analytic definition and the topological definition will coincide?

Comment: I'm not really sure about the answer. Googling around, I found some stuff discussing putting topologies on the power set. I thought you might be interested although they don't answer your question.
 https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133030/defining-a-topology-in-the-power-set
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5886/6265064eb1176cec6463442e2017aadde19a.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The continuity you defined is the special case of upper hemicontinuity for $\mathbb{R}$. There is also the lower hemicontinuity, read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemicontinuity

Lower hemicontinuity is the same as continuity with respect to the lower Vietoris topology. It is the topology generated by $U^-=\{X\subseteq B\ |\ X\cap U\neq\emptyset\}$ over all open subsets $U\subseteq B$.

Upper hemicontinuity is the same as continuity with respect to the upper Vietoris topology. It is the topology generated by $U^+=\{X\subseteq B\ |\ X\subseteq U\}$ over all open subsets $U\subseteq B$.

I think that in both cases you have to assume that $f$ has closed values, i.e. $f(x)$ is closed for any $x\in A$.